# VBA - Type mismatch error with for loop and 2D array

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

What I am trying to do is copy one array to a temporary array while I resize the original array and then copy the temporary array back to the resized original.

But I am running into the error "type mismatch" when the first for loop runs.

what am I doing wrong to receive this error?

```
Public Sub UpdateNamesPaid(NameValue As String, Paid As String)

    NamesPaid(NamesPaidSize, 0) = NameValue
    NamesPaid(NamesPaidSize, 1) = Paid

    NamesPaidSize = NamesPaidSize + 1
    Dim TempArray() As Variant
    ReDim TempArray(0 To NamesPaidSize, 0 To 1)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    i = 0
    j = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(NamesPaid(i, j)) 

        For j = 0 To UBound(NamesPaid(i, j))

            TempArray(i, j) = NamesPaid(i, j)

        Next j
    Next i

    ReDim NamesPaid(0 To NamesPaidSize, 0 To 1)
    NamesPaid() = TempArray()

End Sub
```

Comment: Off topic... this belongs on Stack Overflow and not SuperUser

Comment: @ethanwu10 That is correct. You should vote to migrate it then so the OP doesn't think they need to double post to get attention.

Comment: @ethanwu10 & CharlieRB: VBA is not off-topic here.  See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4565/inconsistent-mod-response-to-migrating-excel-questions-between-stack-overflow.  This should not be closed, migrated, re-posted, bent, folded, or mutilated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how the `UBound()` function's parameters are meant: first parameter is the array name, second is the dimension which you are looking at.
The correct code would be:

```
    Public Sub UpdateNamesPaid(NameValue As String, Paid As String)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim NamesPaidSize As Long
    Dim NamesPaid() As String
    ReDim NamesPaid(0 To 0, 0 To 1)

    NamesPaidSize = LBound(NamesPaid, 1) ' or whatever you meant...
    NamesPaid(NamesPaidSize, 0) = NameValue
    NamesPaid(NamesPaidSize, 1) = Paid

    Dim TempArray() As String
    ReDim TempArray(0 To NamesPaidSize, 0 To 1)


    For i = LBound(NamesPaid, 1) To UBound(NamesPaid, 1)
        For j = LBound(NamesPaid, 2) To UBound(NamesPaid, 2)
            TempArray(i, j) = NamesPaid(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    NamesPaidSize = NamesPaidSize + 1
    ReDim NamesPaid(0 To NamesPaidSize, 0 To 1)

   ' NamesPaid = TempArray
    For i = LBound(TempArray, 1) To UBound(TempArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(TempArray, 2) To UBound(TempArray, 2)
             NamesPaid(i, j) = TempArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Be warned that this might be very inefficient for increments of 1. You could make the initial array of size 10, fill that up, then put in the copy step and increment another 10.